# Ternary Operators and exit statements

Tags: php

Hey everyone I have this one line of code, and I was thinking about something, is this considered a legal assignment of a variable or will it cause errors. Furthermore is it okay to use exit() statements like this, or am I just terrible at coding somedays? Also if there is a duplicate question like this, please point me in the right direction that would be fanastic!

```
list($foo, $bar) ? generateValues($data) : exit("Unable to obtain useful information);
```

Comment: Why don't you run it and try it yourself?

Comment: *"is this considered a legal assignment of a variable or will it cause errors"* - Everything's legal, doesn't necessarily mean it will work, have you tried it?

Comment: don't have the means at the moment

Comment: Can't you access http://codepad.org/ or http://ideone.com/ ?

Comment: [Here's the means](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Erm...no.  Code Review is strictly for already-working code.

Comment: @cHao Well I know that. lol but the OP doesn't seem to ;)

Comment: There's a missing quote at the end of your exit string. Just so you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list() you are using will assign $foo and $bar values if you use it like so:

```
list($foo,$bar) = array('fooValue', 'barValue');
```

so to properly use it in a tertiary statement would be like so:

```
list($foo, $bar) = (conditional) ? generateValues($data) : exit('...');
```

the exit will fire if the conditional is false, otherwise the array generated by generateValues() will be returned by the assignment, and list() will assign the values respectively.

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php).