# Exit a ternary operator when the condition is true

Tags: php

I have this code

```
public function check_if_exists(){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM authors WHERE first_name = 'Evanhd'");
    $row = $query->row()->count;
    echo ($row == 0 ? 'this is true' : 'this is false');
    echo 'execution reached here....';
    }
```

that checks if a condition is true and displays appropriate message.

How can i prevent the script executing further when the condition is true, within the ternary operator and also when the operator is false?

Comment: Use an `if` statement instead.

Comment: I asked for the ternary operator to save myself lots of lines in my code.

Comment: _"...when the condition is true... and also when the operator is false?"_ - you mean always?

Comment: for check_if_exists, just do `return (bool) $query->row()->count;`

Comment: "lots of lines" means `if ($row !== 0) return false;` ?

Comment: I just want a way to use exit from within the ternary operator @El_Vanja  ... and no, i want to use exit when the condition is only true in one line and in another line where the condition is false, i use exit.

Comment: Oh, I see, I though you were talking about the same line. You can't perform multiple commands in a ternary.

Comment: @El_Vanja have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/a/26287120

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough with my previous comment. I didn't mean you couldn't exit from it, I meant you can't perform something like `$cond ? something; exit; : somethingElse; exit;`. Nevermind. But, if you use `exit` it won't only stop the execution of the function, it will kill the script that calls the function as well. I think you're overcomplicating the situation for yourself in order to save a couple of lines of code.

Comment: @Gandalf A ternary expects two (or three if you count the condition itself) expressions. A return statement is not an expression so can't be used in a ternary, nor should you want to. You should be aiming for maintainability/readability of your code. Not shortness. Being clever with ternary's makes code almost always harder to read instead of easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return from a ternary operator like this.

There is a programming pattern called 'Return early', you can read more about it for example here: https://medium.com/swlh/return-early-pattern-3d18a41bba8

You should check the condition with an `if` statement and return (with `null` or `false`) if the condition is not met.

Like this:

```
public function check_if_exists(){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM authors WHERE first_name = 'Evanhd'");
    $row = $query->row()->count;
    if ($row === 0) {
        return false;
    }

    echo 'execution reached here.... lets continue';
}
```